# How can I handle the variable uninitialized error in tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to write python scripts to achieve style transfer mainly using keras. 
But I was stuck by an error.

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar124 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable 
was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar124/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
         [[{{node loss/block5_pool_loss/dummy_loss/weighted_loss/ExpandDims/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar124 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar124/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
         [[node loss/block5_pool_loss/dummy_loss/weighted_loss/ExpandDims/ReadVariableOp (defined at D:\Tool\python3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_16987]Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Errors are showed. I have searched for this, and many people said that I should use this to initialize variables. But this util is deprecated.

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

And I found somebody else said I should use this. Though it is working, it needs sessions to run it. However, there is no session in the tensorflow v2.

```
init = tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables()
```

I wonder how can I fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code is written using **Tensorflow 1**.

Just like using `init = tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables()` there is also a compat version of **Session variable**.

`sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()`

You could read more about the **compat library** or the Tensorflow 1 functions that are **imported** to Tensorflow 2 for **compatibility**. 
But I would highly suggest to **re-code** your whole code into Tensorflow 2, to **benefit from the optimizations** provided.

Read more about **Tensorflow Compat** library [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat).

Comment: So can you tell us how to do it in TF2.0? I have the same problem and I don't know how to address it in tf2 (I mean, without compat library and sessions).